# Problema com largura de componentes com form-inline bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou construindo um formulário e estou com dificuldade de organizar os componentes do formulário do jeito que eu gostaria.

Quando uso a classe `col-md` do bootstrap os componentes estão ficando todo desconfigurados e quando eu mexo o tamanho dos campos pelo CSS, quando é usado a responsividade os componentes ficam todos desalinhados.

Qual a melhor forma para conseguir mexer nas larguras do componentes?

Eu gostaria de aumentar o tamanho do DropDown e também do Input Text, deixando todos componentes na mesma linha e de forma responsiva.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!-- MENU -->
<div class="page-bar">
    <ul class="page-breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <a href="/Pais/Index"> Pais </a>
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- MENU -->
</br>

<form class="form-inline" role="form">

    <!-- BOTAO NOVO -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red">
            Novo
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- DROPDOWN CAMPOS PESQUISA -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="dropdownColunasPesquisa">
            <option>Todos...</option>
            <option>Handle</option>
            <option>Descrição</option>
            <option>Sigla</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- TEXTBOX PESQUISA -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar">
    </div>

    <!-- BOTAO PESQUISAR -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red">
            Pesquisar
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Com o **`form-inline`** você consegue usar a atributo **`size`**, para determinar a largura dos seus inputs, porém o bootstrap faz o reposicionamento na tela devido a responsividade.

Se você utilizar o **`form-horizontal`**, todos campos sempre serão do mesmo tamanho.

Uma última dica pra você testar, pode criar uma folha de estilo css separada e suprimir o funcionamento de alguma propriedade do bootstrap usando o !important:

`.classe-nova{
      width: 'x pixels' !important;
}`

Aí você coloca essa classe no elemento que deseja alterar e recomendo nunca alterar diretamente as classes do bootstrap, afinal o que serve em uma página, nem sempre fica bom em outra. Abraço.